# creating a function to sobstitute binary to words using vowel=0 consonant=1

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I'm trying to create a python program to encrypt(obfuscate?) a binary code so that each 0 will become a vowel and each 1 a consonant and there will be only words of complete meaning: for example the bin number 10110 will beacome HELLO. the following code is the program i wrote, but i can't find a way to perform the "encription"

```
import binascii

#to convert from ascii to bin / from bin  to ascii
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(text.encode(encoding, errors)), 16))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))

def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return int2bytes(n).decode(encoding, errors)

#making a wordlist
f = open("/home/unkn0wn/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/wordlist.txt","r")
list1 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
f.close()
vocali = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

#vowels = 0, consonants = 1
def trasform(word):
    lista_parola = list(word)
    empty = []
    for i in lista_parola:
        if i in vocali:
            empty.append('0')
        else:
            empty.append('1')
    binar = "".join(empty)
    return binar
bin_list = []
for i in list1:
    bin_list.append(trasform(i))

#creations of a dict
dizionario = dict(zip(bin_list, list1))

def cript(text):
    testo_in_bin = text_to_bits(text)
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate a dictionary that maps bitmasks to a list of corresponding words to choose from. Let's say you have file `words.txt`, which looks like this:

```
the
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
lazy
dog
```

This function reads each word from `words.txt`, maps the vowels to `0` and the consonants to `1`, and creates- and returns a dictionary whose keys are possible bitmasks, and the associated values are lists of corresponding words. I'm making some assumptions here - like the file will only contain lowercase characters and a newline to separate the words.

```
def generate_mask():

    from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

    vowels = set("aeiou")
    consonants = set(alphabet) ^ vowels

    mapping = str.maketrans(
        "".join(vowels) + "".join(consonants),
        ("0" * len(vowels)) + ("1" * len(consonants))
    )

    mask = {}

    with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
        for word in map(str.rstrip, file):
            key = word.translate(mapping)
            if key not in mask:
                mask[key] = []
            mask[key].append(word)

    return mask
```

The returned `mask` in this case would be a dictionary, which looks like:

```
{
    '110': ['the'],
    '10011': ['quick'],
    '11011': ['brown'],
    '101': ['fox', 'dog'],
    '101101': ['jumped'],
    '0101': ['over'],
    '1011': ['lazy']
}
>>>
```

As you can see, `fox` and `dog` share the same bitmask, so they end up in the same list.

Then, you'd use this like this:

```
def main():

    from random import choice

    mask = generate_mask()

    values = ["101", "1011", "101", "101"]

    for value in values:
        print(choice(mask[value]))
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
dog
lazy
fox
dog
>>>
```

Comment: that should work, thank you. The only problem is to find a way to choose in how many characters should i divide the value so that I'm sure that  a word which fits in the value exist

Comment: You might want to add in digits as well as letters.  Even digits correspond to `0` and odd digits to `1`.  That will let you fill in spare bits that don't fit your word list.